Pen Drive recognized as Cd-ROM
As I mentioned above, my pendrive is recognized as cd-rom on my Win11 OS. And since it is recognized as CD-ROM, I can't format it, can't list in diskpart, or disk management tool. Even Minitool Partition Wizard and EaseUS Partition Master can't recognise it. How I can fix it?

is this something you got for free ? It sounds a lot like those old U3 disks https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U3_(software)

@JourneymanGeek no, it is given as gift with my brand new Opel car.

Is the drive intended to be a basic USB storage device, or is it for delivering specific software or other predefined purpose. I have observed USB drives configured to be read only in order to deliver some software product.

@music2myear I don’t know their intention but it seems simple usb storage device, and there are some user manual files for the car. There is no executable files in it. Just some pdf files…

Then you've answered your question: The drive has some basic protection to minimize the chance of some owner accidentally deleting their manual. This write-protection can be performed in the controller, which you probably cannot circumvent, or in the file system, which diskpart should be able to clear out. Your failures with Minitool and EaseUS seem to indicate it's probably the former.

Probable duplicates: https://superuser.com/questions/950265/formatting-a-bootable-usb-that-thinks-its-a-cd-rom and https://superuser.com/questions/339186/how-can-i-make-a-usb-flash-drive-appear-not-appear-as-a-cd-drive
